# Calculating distance between two points using QGIS C++ APIs

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, measurements, points-to-line, qgsmapcanvas

I have been trying to find the distance between two points using QGIS C++ APIs in Qt. I used the following code :

```
QgsDistanceArea d;
 d.setEllipsoid("WGS84");     
 qDebug()<< "Qgspoint"<< d.measureLine(p1,p2) where p1 and p2 are QgsPoint.
```

My GitHub repository(github.com/PuneetKumar555/QGIS_MAP_OPERATIONS). I made this application. I have also added India.tiff file(raster file) on which I am doing some calculations.

I follow these steps:

1. layer-> add raster layer(india.tiff)
2. geometrical measurements(line geometry) -> draw two line to find distance between them.

It gives correct result (with distanceunits in distancemeters) when I run it from QT IDE. But when I run qgis_demo.exe file from the release folder, the same code gives results in exponential (distance unit in distancedegrees).I am using Qt 5.11.2 for this development. Why is this giving different answer? There is a drastic change in the answer.

When I run from IDE , I get below image

[image]

when I run from .exe file from release folder

[image]

Comment: What is the CRS used by the raster data?

Comment: EPSG:4326 by raster layer

Comment: Have you read https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDistanceArea.html#details and followed the hints about checking `willUseEllipsoid()`?

Answer (score 2):

The second one is in units of degrees.  (1.86e-5 degrees ~= 2km).

Try printing the `lengthUnits` to verify that you're getting what you think you're getting (and then convert if you're getting map units).